# Link that would redirect to AppStore or application (if it's installed)

Tags: android, ios, web, windows-phone

I need to make a link on my website, that would lead to either my application or to that application's page in AppStore. I need it to work on iOS and Android (Windows Phone would be very nice).

I know that I can't detect whether application is installed or not, but maybe there is some native mechanism that would do what I need?

Comment: Check if you can launch you app via the AppURL scheme on iOS, to my knowledge Android does this natively.

Comment: In Windows Phone, when you open your app's page it automatically navigates you to the Store. If your app is already installed, you will see 'view' button instead of 'install'.